# Toast makeText can't resolve symbol "MyActivity.this"

Tags: java, android, firebase

I was trying to set `Toast`, to show is registratiion was succesful of failed. But couldn't make it resolve the `context`. There is the code:

```
private void RegisterAccount() {
        String username = RegisterUsername.getText().toString();
        String mail = RegisterMail.getText().toString();
        String password = RegisterPassword.getText().toString();

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        User user = new User(username, mail);

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

                                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())

                                .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterAccount.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterAccount.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterAccount.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'RegisterAccount'`
for all 3 `Toast`-s

I tried `Toast.makeText(RegisterAccount(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`, `RegisterAccount()` instead of `RegisterAccount.this` and got error: `Cannot resolve method 'makeText(void, java.lang.String, int)'`.

Comment: Have you tried to use blazc's answer?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or:

```
Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I tried both, and got the same error. But thanks.

Comment: Is this function in MainActivity or somewhere else?

Comment: I solved it by creating `Context RegisterAccountContext = getBaseContext();` variable and putting it in place of `context` in `Toast`.

Comment: This function is in the RegisterActivity. And I called it in the same Activity.